# Get all records value is not 1 in Laravel

Tags: laravel

How can I get all records from the table where `status` value is `0` or `NULL` on Laravel?

`DB::table('categories')->where('status', '!=', 1)` 
returns only records where `status=0`

P.S. I need multiple conditions here, so raw query is not so good choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said you'll have another where conditionals, so you need to use a [closure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#parameter-grouping):

```
DB::table('categories')->where(function($q) {
    $q->whereNull('status')->orWhere('status', 0);
})
// Other where conditionals.
->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [orWhereNull](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_orWhereNull):

```
DB::table('categories')->where('status', '=', '0')->orWhereNull('status')->get();
```

Comment: if my where also has another 5 conditions, it gets very complicated then?